# Why do I get an error for trying to access a builtin class method attribute but not the same builtin function attribute

Tags: python

I'm attempting to mess around with python bytecode (wordcode in 3.6), just to have some exploratory fun. I'm using byteplay3 to change the `__code__` attribute, and all is fine and dandy when working with functions.

```
from byteplay3 import *

def foo():
    print('bar')

def monty():
    print('python')

c = Code.from_code(foo.__code__)
d = Code.from_code(monty.__code__)

foo.__code__ = d.to_code()
```

output:

```
>>>foo()
python
```

When I try the same thing with a class method,

```
class King(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print('King of the Britons')

    def bro(self):
        print('bruh')

Arthur = King()

f = Code.from_code(Arthur.bro.__code__)
```

everything works fine until I try and alter the `__code__` attribute of the class method.

```
Arthur.bro.__code__ = d.to_code()
```

I get the "'method has no attribute `__code__`" error, when I'm fairly sure there is one. I can `print(f.code)`, or disassemble `Arthur.bro.__code__` with the dis module and I get

```
  24         1 LOAD_GLOBAL          print
             2 LOAD_CONST           'bruh'
             3 CALL_FUNCTION        1
             4 POP_TOP              
             5 LOAD_CONST           None
             6 RETURN_VALUE
```

so, what am I missing? I'm a bit new to python, so I'm guessing it's something rather simple, but it has been vexing me all week.

Comment: `Arthur` is an instance, not a class. As such, it does not actually have the class methods directly attached to it - it references them through its class. Try `King.bro.__code__` instead, or `Arthur.__class__.bro.__code__`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here appears to be the difference between classes and objects (or, instances of a class). Bytecode is assembled for each class, not each instance of the class. To get the behaviour you want in your example, you need to do something like the below.

```
# two example classes
class Cat():
    def says(self):
        print('meow!')

class Dog():
    def says(self):
        print('woof!')
# setup as objects
c, d = Cat(), Dog()
# change the class bytecode
Dog.says.__code__ = Cat.says.__code__
# and we get a very confused dog...
d.says() # 'meow!'
```